# keycloak include realms's property in Custom Required Action Mail

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak 21. I have created a custom required action by implementing the RequiredActionProvider interface. Now I want to include additional information stored in the realms attributes in the Mail, that is send when assigning the Action to an user. I found no way for this, since the methods evaluateTriggers or processAction are executed later. Is there a way to achive this?